# How to load Fallout 4 saves from my PC?

Tags: fallout-4

The title might be a little confusing, I will try to elaborate on it here.
So I have Fallout 4 on Steam, and I had been (Now disabled) using Steam Cloud to sync my saved games. I kinda like accidentally load the previous saves instead of the latest one and the game saves got overwritten. I know there is a save folder as the \My Games\Fallout 4\saves where there a .FOS files. I wanna know if I can revert my saves by loading one of the saves in the folder or does the saves folder also gets overwritten when the ones in-game does?

If I can revert or load a previous save, then how?

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't understand how your saves get overwritten by loading a previous save. Never experienced anything like this with Steam Cloud or good old saving on the hard disk. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Every save, be it Quicksave, Autosave or Manual Save, has a time stamp right? So what happened is that when I load a game from ( Lets assume 2d10h, but my latest save is at 2d16h) previous save, the 2d10h save becomes the latest save and all saves beyond 2d10h is missing. Therefore, I couldn't return to my 2d16h save and my progress is lost.

Comment: That's not how it works. Yes, it will overwrite auto saves and quick saves should you choose to play with the old save(i.e. change areas and press the quick save button). But manual saves will never be affected by that. There is no possibility that a manual save is overwritten unless you yourself choose to overwrite that save. If for some reason Fallout 4 hides saves, because they aren't your "latest save" (though again, this is not something I've ever experienced), you may try to remove the wrong saves from your save-folder (check the last modified date & time to determine which ones)

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! The body text is a little garbled, but I think we get what you mean, and you mention learning English in your profile, so that makes sense. Here's your first upvote.